# How to access HardwarePropertiesManager on Android Things

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, android-things, device-owner

I have a raspberry pi installed with the android things developer preview.

I would like to monitor the CPU temperature and usage of the raspberry itself.

My approach was to use the HardwarePropertiesManager like this:

```
HardwarePropertiesManager hardware = (HardwarePropertiesManager) getSystemService(Context.HARDWARE_PROPERTIES_SERVICE);
float[] cpuTemperature = hardware.getDeviceTemperatures(HardwarePropertiesManager.DEVICE_TEMPERATURE_CPU, HardwarePropertiesManager.TEMPERATURE_CURRENT);
```

This call requires device owner or profile owner permissions (or vr).

I never used device owner so I followed the explanations on these links:

[Android Kiosk Mode Example](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/)

[Android Shell Command DPM](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.de/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html)

But I get the following error in adb shell:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{com.myexample.androidthings/com.myexample.androidthings.BasicDeviceAdminReceiver} as device owner.
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:149)
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:96)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myexample.androidthings.service">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>

    <activity android:name="com.myexample.androidthings.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Launch activity automatically on boot -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"></service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.myexample.androidthings.BasicDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_policies"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Did someone experience this error in the past an can give me a hint where I need to look for the error.
Maybe my approach is also incorrect and I can get the CPU measurements in a simpler way.

Comment: Please file a bug report regarding the issue you are having obtaining the proper permissions to use this API: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20bug%20report

Comment: Hi, have you solved it?

Comment: same here. Did you find out why?

Answer (score 0):

Change intent-filter to this

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
```